# Force joined view not to be optimized

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, view

I have a somewhat complex view which includes a join to another view. For some reason the generated query plan is highly inefficient. The query runs for many hours. However if I select the sub-view into a temporary table first and then join with this, the same query finished in a few minutes.

My question is: Is there some kind of query hint or other trick which will force the optimizer to execute the joined sub-view in isolation before performing the join, just as when using a temp table? Clearly the default strategy chosen by the optimizer is not optimal.

I cannot use the temporary table-trick since views does not allow temporary tables. I understand I could probably rewrite everything to a stored procedure, but that would break composeability of views, and it seems also like bad for maintenance to rewrite everything just to trick the optimizer to not use a bad optimization.

Comment: Perhaps a hint? Like this: `SELECT * FROM YourView WITH (INDEX(0))`. That, in theory, should force it to not use any indexes...

Comment: When you have views joining views you can get some really god awful execution plans. This is because of the way the optimizer works. I will see if I can find some references to this.

Comment: Here is a decent discussion on the topic with several links to more discussions. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5487/is-nested-view-a-good-database-design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Adam Machanic](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/) explained one such way at a SQL Saturday I recently attended.  The presentation was called [Clash of the Row Goals](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2014/04/26/sql-saturday-chicago-291-clash-of-the-row-goals-demos.aspx).  The method involves using a TOP X at the beginning of the sub-select.  He explained that when doing a TOP X, the query optimizer assumes it is more efficient to grab the TOP X rows one at a time.  As long as you set X as a sufficiently large number (limit of INT or BIGINT?), the query will always get the correct results.

So one example that Adam provided:

```
SELECT
    x.EmployeeId,
    y.totalWorkers
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS x
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        y0.ManagerId, 
        COUNT(*) AS totalWorkers
    FROM HumanResources.Employee AS y0
    GROUP BY 
        y0.ManagerId
) AS y ON
    y.ManagerId = x.ManagerId
```

becomes:

```
SELECT
    x.EmployeeId,
    y.totalWorkers
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS x
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TOP(2147483647)
        y0.ManagerId, 
        COUNT(*) AS totalWorkers
    FROM HumanResources.Employee AS y0
    GROUP BY 
        y0.ManagerId
) AS y ON
    y.ManagerId = x.ManagerId
```

It is a super cool trick and very useful.

Comment: Kind of ugly, but certainly better than having to rewrite the whole query logic.

Comment: So cool. A current link to the mentoned presentation: https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event14/Query_Tuning_Mastery_Clash_of_the_Row_Goals - well worth the watch.

Answer (score 1):

When things get messy the query optimize often resorts to loop joins
If materializing to a temp fixed it then most likely that is the problem

The optimizer often does not deal with views very well
I would rewrite you view to not uses views

[Join Hints (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx)

You may be able to use these hints on views

Try merge and hash
Try changing the order of join

Move condition into the join whenever possible

```
select * 
  from table1 
  join table2
    on table1.FK = table2.Key 
 where table2.desc = 'cat1'
```

should be

```
select * 
  from table1 
  join table2
    on table1.FK = table2.Key 
   and table2.desc = 'cat1'
```

Now the query optimizer will get that correct but as the query gets more complex the query optimize goes into what I call stupid mode and loop joins.  But that is also done to protect the server and have as little in memory as possible.